# Installed PHP using phpbrew, Now phpmyadmin is giving mbstring extension error

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, mbstring

Installed earlier version of PHP on a new Ubuntu installation using phpbrew and now my phpmyadmin is throwing an error.

The error reads:

```
The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I have uninstalled and reinstalled phpmyadmin, restarted the apache server to no avail.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: PHP version is 5.4.35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing the various versions of php I had to add in the modules

```
phpbrew install 5.4.34 +apxs2 +default +mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

To install mbstring,

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

restart your apache server

and.. check into your php.ini to activate extension.

Comment: This is what happened: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-php5 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-windows-live libupstart1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: So I looked into the php.ini file and uncommented the mbstring dll and then restarted the apache2 server. Still not working. Any other ideas?

Specifically 

extension=php_mbstring.dll

Comment: into ubunto.. it is a "so" file.. not "dll".. but look into phpinfo() if you see it

Comment: it is not listed within the phpinfo() file.

Comment: I tried adding .so instead of .dll and restarted. It did not work.

Comment: keep .dll .. but sorry i dont know what is your problem..  except rebuild php with the flag for mbstring I don't know what is problem... if you do "sudo service apache2 restart" and nothing append..

Comment: I think it is extension link dynamic not working. Will work on that for now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way helped me is 
`sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext`
My system - Ubuntu 16.04 server 64 bit, PHP7.0 Apache2